# Interactive Legend on force layout with d3.legend

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, legend

I am looking to create an interactive legend. I'm working on a force directed graph that is being populated from a .csv file. I would like for the nodes to be highlighted when mouseover on the legend. I am using the d3.legend library that was created by Susie Lu for my legend.

I was also testing that whenever I hover on a node, other nodes with the same size will be highlighted. However, it is not working. I noticed examples were previously given by Mike Bostock such as this //bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3087986 .I have also referred to Mike Bostok's answer to a similar question stackoverflow.com/questions/11206015/clicking-a-node-in-d3-from-a-button-outside-the-svg/11211391#11211391 but to no success.  Ulitmately I would like my Force Layout to look something like this bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/raw/2879486/ Can anyone kindly point out my noob mistake?

```
        var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("r", function(d) { return d.size; })
       .attr("class", function(d) { return "node " + d.size; })
      .style("fill", function (d) { return color(d.group); })
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { highlight(d.size); });

            node.append("circle")
                    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                    .attr("r",function(d) { return d.size; });

function highlight(type) {
   if (type == null) d3.selectAll(".node").classed("active", false);
   else d3.selectAll(".node." + type).classed("active", true);
}
```

Please refer to http://jsfiddle.net/rajaiskandar/os8622yb/ on the full coding. Is there any way for me to upload my .csv file to jsfiddle? I have customised the les_mis.csv .

This is what it currently looks like

[image: print screen of the force layout]

Thank you in advance

Comment: The fiddle isn't working. There is no way to add a csv. You could add dummy data that represents your real data.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I am now using plnkr for the full code. Please refer to the link http://plnkr.co/edit/JGYS5grLzqrfn5GFj87q?p=preview . Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one of the problems is that CSS classes can't start with digits (in your case, 5, 10, 15, etc. are class names for the groups that contain the circles). See [the CSS specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#characters).

Here's the specific cite:

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A1 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); they cannot start with a digit, or a hyphen followed by a digit.
>   Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any ISO 10646
>   character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance, the
>   identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

Another problem is that (presumably) you want to be targeting the circles themselves and not the whole group, which has the class .node.15. Suppose you changed the digit classes to start with an underscore. Then d3.selectAll(".node._15") would target all groups with circles of size 15. You could then target the circles by replacing the second line in your highlight function by something like:

```
d3.selectAll(".node._" + type.size + ">circle")
```

The last thing (I think) is that because of CSS specificity, targeting the items with a the class .node.active will not overwrite the styling that has been added to the elements directly in the html. Replacing "style" by "attr" when you define the fill color of the svg elements should fix this.

Does this work? http://plnkr.co/edit/6E0fkDWS87jYi4zbyPnd?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for taking the time and effort to explain it well. I will digest your explanation and try it on. The example that you have put on plnkr works brilliantly on hovering over the nodes with the same size. My next step is to make it work with the d3.legend as this is my initial goal. Then create a mouseout function. Thanks again! I will let you know if I get it to work with the d3.legend.

Answer (score 0):

If you analyze your code with a developer tool, such as firebug, you will get this error message when you hover over one of your nodes:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'querySelectorAll' on 'Document': '.node.5' is not a valid selector.
```

The circles don't have the correct css classes.

Also, you are passing something that is not defined into your highlight function. Try using highlight(d) instead of highlight(d.size).

Comment: I'm sorry, it is still not working after changing the highlight(d)